# Javascript String replace white spaces before and after multiple selectors

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I have a string with multimple whitespaces between words and I want to reduce all the whitespace to just one.And after to delete the whitespace before and after[',','.','?','!'] and let one space after ','.
Can you help me with a code?

Comment: So basically: "How do I remove spaces from a string?"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: @StephanBijzitter: Well, as per the current question version, it is not.

Comment: Well, now, it is just a duplicate/off-topic. Please don't change your requirements, or just post a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach does not work because you only escape the first space in your `newSeparators`, while `.` and `?` remain special regex metacharacters, and `/\ . /` regex matches a space, any char, a space, and `/\ ? /` will match an optional space and 1 space after.

I suggest using:

```
/\s*([.!:?])\s*|\s*(,)\s*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FqRwXx/2).

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `([.!:?])` - Group 1 capturing `.`, `!`, `:` or `?`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `\s*(,)\s*` - a `,` in between 0+ whitespaces captured into Group 2.

```js
var newSeparators = /\s*([.!:?])\s*|\s*(,)\s*/g;
var data = "word, word . word ! word ? word";
data = data.replace(newSeparators, function($0, $1, $2) {
  return $2 ?  $2 + " " : " " + $1 + " ";
});
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Yes thanks but I have one more issue.The data I want to format is a long text and is not all the time of this type: word , word . word ! word ? word . Sometimes I have : word, word and I want to have just one white space between seperators.The code will make word ,  word(with 2 whitespace  after comma)

Comment: Yes, and what is the problem? Post the text and explain what is different from your sample input. It is not clear what you mean, sorry. Right now, this solution resolves the issue in the original post.

Comment: Thanks I can have the result that I want with this code If I format it a little bit.